# Get all the users count according to type in one query instead of multiple query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a MySQL query where I want to get data from one table only. Where structure looks like this:

```
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment |
| name               | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| lastname           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| slug               | text             | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| gender             | varchar(225)     | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| balance            | double(50,6)     | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| email              | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| password           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                | 
| city               | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| country            | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| statename          | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| countryname        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| dob                | date             | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| membership         | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | standard |                |
| status             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| marital_status     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| description        | text             | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| user_id            | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL     |                |
| active             | smallint(6)      | NO   |     | 1        |                |
| registertype       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | unpaid   |                |
| created_at         | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| updated_at         | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL     |                              
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
```

Now I want to select data like this with below columns:

```
1) created_at (will be a date)
2) total_registrations (will be total count)
3) paid_member (count of total member where registertype=paid on a specific date)
4) unpaid_member (count of total member where registertype=unpaid on a specific date wise)
```

So far I am successful to get the results like this with below query:

```
select DATE(`created_at`) as created_at, count(*) as total_registrations 
from en_customers 
where DATE(`created_at`)  between date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 7 day) AND CURDATE() 
    AND registertype="paid"  
group by DATE(`created_at`);
```

From this query I get this result:

```
+------------+-----------+
| created_at | total_reg |
+------------+-----------+
| 2018-07-04 |         7 |
| 2018-07-05 |         7 |
| 2018-07-06 |         5 |
| 2018-07-07 |         4 |
| 2018-07-08 |         8 |
| 2018-07-09 |        13 |
| 2018-07-10 |        15 |
| 2018-07-11 |        14 |
+------------+-----------+
```

But I am not not able to take the records with columns I just show.

Thank you (in advance)!

Comment: The syntax is clearly MySQL -- and not SQL Server.  I changed the tags.  In the future, please tag appropriately.

Comment: Sure I will make sure that tags will be properly mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
select DATE(`created_at`) as created_at, count(*) as total_registrations 
    ,sum(case when registertype='paid' then 1 else 0 end) as paid_member
    ,sum(case when registertype='unpaid' then 1 else 0 end) as unpaid_member
from en_customers 
where DATE(`created_at`)  between date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 7 day) AND CURDATE()  
group by DATE(`created_at`);
```

The technique is called "Conditional Aggregation".

Note I removed the `registertype="paid"` condition from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Amazing it worked! This is the fastest method of doing it? Or is there any faster way of querying the same?

Comment: Yes I saw one more person answer same as yours :)

Comment: SUM vs COUNT I guess sum might take more processing, where `count` is taking less processing. The result you shared showed up in 0.06s and with `count` its showing in 0.05s.

Comment: `SUM()` and `COUNT()` do different things. A `0` is still "counted".

Answer (score 1):

use `CASE WHEN` in `COUNT` function.

```
select DATE(`created_at`) as created_at,
       count(*) as total_registrations,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN registertype='paid' THEN 1 END) as paid_member,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN registertype='unpaid' THEN 1 END) as unpaid_member 
from en_customers 
where DATE(`created_at`)  between date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 7 day) AND CURDATE() 
group by DATE(`created_at`);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use sum on filtered  values

```
select DATE(`created_at`) as created_at
      , count(*) as total_registrations 
      , sum(case when registertype='paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid_member
      , sum(case when registertype='unpaid' then 1 else 0 end) unpaid_member
from en_customers 
where DATE(`created_at`)  between date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 7 day) AND CURDATE() 

group by DATE(`created_at`);
```

Comment: What is better SUM or COUNT?

Comment: the count  .. count(*) the number of rows where there is a value , th count(colname) count the number of rows where the column is not null, count(distinct colname) count the distinct value not null but for filter rows  you should use sum for add  1 only for the true values in rows